# Beamer: Transparent AND centered background image on intro slide

Tags: beamer, graphics, horizontal-alignment, backgrounds, transparency

I know this is similar to other questions. Other answers address either:

1. Adding a transparent image
2. Centering an image but I cannot find an answer with both.

With previous answers I can successfully make my image transparent OR centered, but not both. I've tried integrating methods for the two with no luck.

Here's the code I'm using on my introduction slide

```
\usepackage{tikz}

    \usebackgroundtemplate{ 
         \vbox to \paperheight
              {\tikz \node[opacity=0.2] 
                 {\vfil\hbox to \paperwidth
                     {\hfil\includegraphics[width=1.5in]{name.png}
                  \hfil}\vfil} ;  }
            }
```

Comment: Does this help? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74038/transparent-image-background-in-beamer

Comment: That is the post from which I got the \tikz part of my above code. But the code in your link does not center the image. Using the code from that post my image is automatically flush left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining the work of [Transparent image background in beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74038/transparent-image-background-in-beamer) and [Image on full slide in beamer package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/image-on-full-slide-in-beamer-package/3927#3927), you can do something like:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, centered on slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: sample output]

You have to compile twice to get the image centered.

Comment: You also need to think of the aspect ratio.

Comment: @Karl'sstudents: good point.  Back when I was doing a lot of beamer stuff I thought about a macro that would maximize the image size to fit the aspect ratio.  But I never got around to it.

Comment: Why do you need the `remember picture` option?

Comment: @Kevin: the `remember picture` key is useful when you want to mark a position *on the page* rather than within the picture.  You can see it documented in Section 16.13.2 of the pgf v2.10 manual.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: I thought `overlay` is used for that purpose (as I understand it, `overlay` is like drawing a bounding box of zero dimension, so that the TikZ picture doesn't affect the positioning of other materials on the page). `remember picture`, according to the manual is used so that you can later on refer to nodes in the current picture.

Comment: @Kevin: If you download the example above and remove the `remember picture` key before compiling, the image doesn't show up on the current page at all.   I see your point why it doesn't seem necessary, but it is necessary for this example at least.  Perhaps `remember picture` is needed to refer to *any* remembered pictures, not just the current one?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: You're right. This does seem strange...