# Put a beamer background image in the right bottom corner

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, graphics, backgrounds

In beamer, I like to place a background image in all my slides. So I could use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108356/beamer-transparent-and-centered-background-image-on-intro-slide):

```
\usebackgroundtemplate{
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{background.png}};
}
```

However, to put the background image at the right-bottom corner, what should I do? I guess I should change some how "current page.center" to something like "current page.south east". But, I want to match the right-bottom corner of the image file with the right-bottom corner of the slides.

Comment: Add `anchor=south east` together with `at=(current page.south east)`. Moreover, you'd probably also want to set `inner sep=0` to avoid unnecessary white spaces.

Comment: @KevinC Thanks! Could you add as an answer so that I can pick?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `anchor=south east` together with `at=(current page.south east)`. Moreover, you'd probably also want to set `inner sep=0` to avoid unnecessary white spaces.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mwe} % provides example image

\usebackgroundtemplate{
  \tikz[overlay,remember picture] 
  \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.south east),anchor=south east,inner sep=0pt] {
    \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{image}};
}

\begin{document}
\frame{frame content}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]