# How to include a background image to only one page of a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer

How to include a background image to only one page, any page, of a beamer presentation?

With reference to [Beamer: Transparent AND centered background image on intro slide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108356/beamer-transparent-and-centered-background-image-on-intro-slide)

How can I include the background to only one page of the beamer presentation?

Comment: Look at [this question and answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78470/39194).

Comment: This [question and answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/image-on-full-slide-in-beamer-package) were useful to me. I hope it works to you too.

Answer (score 17):

You can declare the background just before the slide, and un-declare it just after it.:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, not here
\end{frame}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%             declare it
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
}

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, centered on slide
\end{frame}

\usebackgroundtemplate{ }    %% undeclare it

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, not here
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use a group on the other hand:

```
\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
}

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, centered on slide
\end{frame}

\egroup
```

Comment: Neither of these methods work when using a theme (i.e. Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw).

Comment: This formulation has no effect whatsoever with TexLive 2022.