# Make a slide background optional in Beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I've got a background in my custom template which I'd like to be able to switch off for certain slides.  Ideally I'd do this with an option to `\begin{frame}`.  My template is very loosely based on the approach in [Claudio Fiandrino's answer to "Design a custom Beamer theme from scratch"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146682/28808).

I've seen [How to insert a background image in a beamer frame?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7916/28808) and [How to include a background image to only one page of a beamer presentation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/201013/28808); what I'm looking for is essentially the reverse of the latter, but cleanly (if I get this template right I won't be the only one using it so I wan't it to be robust).

This ends up being quite a lot of code just for an MWE.  The most relevant bit is probably first, in **`beaminnerthemecf.sty`**:

```
\mode<presentation>

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \useasboundingbox[inner sep=0] (0,0) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
  \node[anchor=north,opacity=0.25] (bkg) at (current page.north) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}};
  \fill[color=red,anchor=north west] (0,\the\paperheight) rectangle(\the\paperwidth,0.85\paperheight);
  \node[anchor= south east, red,align=right] at (0.975\paperwidth,0.025\paperheight){\normalsize\insertauthor\\[0.2em]\normalsize\insertdate};  
  \ifnum\thepage>1\relax%
    \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      {\node[anchor=north west, white,font=\Large] at (0.025\paperwidth,0.975\paperheight){\insertframetitle};}
      \else{%
        \node[anchor=north west, white,font=\Large] at (0.025\paperwidth,0.985\paperheight){\insertframetitle};%
        \node[anchor=north west, white,font=\large] at (0.025\paperwidth,0.925\paperheight){\insertframesubtitle};%
      }%
     \fi
   \fi
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

% Title page
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{cf}[1][]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shift={(current page.south west)}]
        \useasboundingbox (current page.south west) rectangle(\paperwidth,\paperheight);
        \node[anchor=center, red,inner sep=0,align=center,text width=0.8\paperwidth] at (0.5\paperwidth,0.5\paperheight){\inserttitle};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% Items
\setbeamertemplate{items}[square]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]
\mode<all>
```

to test it we can compile **`dummy.tex`**:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\title{\Large{\textbf{There Is No Largest Prime Number}}}
\date[ISPN ’80]{27th International Symposium of Prime Numbers}
\author[Euclid]{Euclid of Alexandria \texttt{euclid@alexandria.edu}}
\usetheme{cf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame} % This is where I'd like to turn off the background image
\frametitle{There Is No Largest Prime Number} 
\framesubtitle{The proof uses \textit{reductio ad absurdum}.} 
This is a test
\begin{enumerate}
\item Suppose $p$ were the largest prime number. 
\item Let $q$ be the product of the first $p$ numbers. 
\item Then $q+1$ is not divisible by any of them. 
\item But $q + 1$ is greater than $1$, thus divisible by some prime
number not in the first $p$ numbers.
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Also needed are **`beamerouterthemecf.sty`**:

```
\mode<presentation>
% Frame title
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{cf}[1][]{
}
\mode<all>
```

and **`beamercolorthemecf.sty`**:

```
\mode<presentation>
% Settings
\setbeamercolor*{title page header}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{author}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{date}{fg=white}
\setbeamercolor*{item}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=black}
\mode<all>
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/173201/beamer-template-with-different-style-options-for-frames. This shows how to define custom frame options and return to the defaults.

Comment: @samcarter that looks good - I think I can cook something up based on the asnwer to your question

Comment: I agree with the duplicate. My searches didn't turn it up because I was fixated on images; so perhaps this question shoudl serve as a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You can always declare a local empty background.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Background image
\end{frame}

{%-> Starts scope where to apply following template
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
\begin{frame}
No background image
\end{frame}
}%-> Ends scope where particular template has been applied. 

\begin{frame}
Background image, again.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks like the "right" way to do it, but in that case I'd have to find some other way to define the title bar, logo etc.  I think I can see a way to do it based on the link samcarter put in the comments.

Comment: It's supposed that according `beamer-way-of-doing` Title bar, logo, etc are not part of `background` template