# Beamer background

Tags: beamer, graphics

I need a background only for one slide, I need include a picture, like a background, in a unique slide. The background is on all slides but I need a picture in only one slide like a bacgkround. I am using `madrid theme`. Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you know this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7916/how-to-insert-a-background-image-in-a-beamer-frame and this link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78464/background-image-in-beamer-slides

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change the background image for a group (1 or more) of slides, then **before** that group, set

```
% image from https://tranhtreophongkhachdep.com/200-mau-tranh-phong-canh-dep-nui-rung-tay-bac/
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\tikz\node[opacity=.5,yscale=1.5,inner sep=0]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{luavang}};}
```

(let play with some options of the `\includegraphics` command, e.g., `[width=\paperwidth]` and/or some options of the TikZ,'s `\node` command, e.g., `[opacity=.5,yscale=1.5]`, `[inner sep=0]` to get desired background) and then set

```
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
```

**after**  that group of slides to back to the usual background.

[image]

Full example code:
[link on overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/read/grxjknjppckj)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{madrid}
\title{Beamer Template}
\author{TeXstudio Team}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Usual background}
\end{frame}

% image from https://tranhtreophongkhachdep.com/200-mau-tranh-phong-canh-dep-nui-rung-tay-bac/

\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\tikz\node[opacity=.5,yscale=1.5,inner sep=0]{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{luavang}};}
\begin{frame}{A specific background}
\end{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{}

\begin{frame}{Usual background again}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**PS:** As said in [Make a slide background optional in Beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/325220/make-a-slide-background-optional-in-beamer/325228#325228), you can put that group of slides inside a local group `{...}` to locally change the background (and other things if you want).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{madrid}
\title{Beamer Template}
\author{TeXstudio Team}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[plain]
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Usual background}
\end{frame}

{% scope to starting a new background
% image from https://tranhtreophongkhachdep.com/200-mau-tranh-phong-canh-dep-nui-rung-tay-bac/
\setbeamertemplate{background}{
\tikz\node[opacity=.5,yscale=1.5,inner sep=0]   {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{luavang}};}
\begin{frame}{A specific background}
\end{frame}
}% end of the scope of the new background

\begin{frame}{Usual background again}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks, but this background is for all slides, I need background in only one slide.

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez did you compile my code above?

Comment: yes was genial!

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez there is overleaf link https://www.overleaf.com/read/grxjknjppckj

Comment: thanks, but this background is for all slides, I need background in only one slide.

Comment: @julianaperezordoñez nope! Only the 3rd slide has background as the image luavang.jpg; others have no background

Comment: @BlackMild You don't need to fix again `\setbeamertemplate` to revert changes if  changes are made local within a scope. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/325228/1952

Comment: @Ignasi thank you!