# Beamer: Transparent and slightly below the center logo

Tags: beamer

I tried to modify the answer in this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108356/beamer-transparent-and-centered-background-image-on-intro-slide?rq=1&utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

Basically, I would like that the transparent logo would be slightly lower than the center.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center, yshift=-1.5cm)] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, centered on slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, it does not work. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is misplaced `)` in your code, otherwise `yshift` works fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usebackgroundtemplate{%
\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node[opacity=0.3, at=(current page.center),yshift=-100] {
   \includegraphics[height=\paperheight,width=\paperwidth]{example-image-a}};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Background transparent image, centered on slide
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I see from your answer my mistake.

Comment: @Dario I just noticed that you found the `yshift` yourself :)

Comment: Yes. But I put it inside at=(current page.center, yshift=-1.5cm), rather than outside :)

Comment: @Dario Hard to spot :)